# 1200VA UPS Doesn't Supply Power to Monitor

Tags: power-supply, ups, dell-optiplex

I have a DELL Optiplex 7080 Tower PC running on windows 10 pro, and a [Samsung SR35 Monitor](https://www.samsung.com/sg/monitors/flat/sr35-24-inch-ips-fhd-1080p-freesync-ls24r350fzexxs/). I had connected them into a 1200VA Offline UPS, but sometimes, when computer boots up (after the splash screen disappears), the monitor shuts down automatically and the PC remains on. After that I reconnected the power cable of the monitor to the UPS and now the monitor gets power! It works fine!

How to fix this problem?

Comment: I have seen some monitors (not all) stay disconnected when the signal is lost and comes back. I wonder if it is this kind of issue rather than a UPS issue. Transition time of 5 ms should support any monitor.

Comment: Did you try this when the monitor is NOT plugged into the UPS, because it sounds like the monitor might be failing.

Comment: @cybernard The monitor and the PC was plugged into the UPS. After removing and re-connecting the monitor into the UPS, the monitor works fine!

Comment: I've tried today if the monitor works with AC, and it works.